# Setting border width in Excel with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache

I'm using Apache POI, and I configure border this way:

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);

CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
cellStyle.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());

Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(0, cellStyle);
```

But the border in the created document is very thick. Its width is 1.00 pt. I want the border width to be of 0.05 pt (this is default border width when creating Excel document by hands). How can I configure the border width (not the border style)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CellStyle.BORDER_HAIR` for 0.05 pt borders:

```
cellStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_HAIR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: in Apache POI 4.1.2 it is org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle.HAIR